# How to make the ocean become increasingly dark?

Tags: shaders, ocean-simulation

I aldready have a ocean shader and it looks like that:[image: my ocean shader]

but how can i make the ocean become increasingly dark like that "without" ocean modifier?  :[image]

sorry for my english, and thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a volumetric shader plugged into the volume output of a material.

[image]

Add you flavor of surface shader to your liking like a glass, refraction, or mix of transparency and glossy.

Then add a *Volume Scatter* or *Volume Absorption* to the *Volume* socket of the material and adjust both its color and density to your liking.

[image]